# How damaging can a leaky microwave oven be?

Tags: safety, emc, wifi, microwave

This question is mainly about EMC and disruptive RF emissions.

I have noticed recently that each time we use our microwave oven the WiFi network becomes unusably slow (it is still working if you get close to the WiFi router).  When the microwave is turned off, the WiFi recovers and continues as normal.

I've been living with this annoyance for a few days, but now I notice that the WiFi router itself is now suffering from severely degraded WiFi output **all the time**.  I've tried changing channels, to no avail.

Previously there was a good WiFi signal everywhere in the house, but now I can only get a reliable signal if I'm standing a few feet from the router.  The router is about 8 feet away from the microwave oven and there is a wooden staircase between them.

Assuming the (900 Watt Panasonic brand) microwave is to blame for the original WiFi performance issue, could it also be possible that the leaked RF energy has physically damaged the WiFi router's transceiver circuitry?

More to the point, is my microwave dangerous to people in the house?

Comment: A simple test as to leakage can be to put a WiFi device in the microwave, while you ping that device from something outside. When you close the door, the ping should start timing out. If you are still able to ping the device while inside the closed microwave then you need to get rid of that microwave asap. _Note: DO NOT TURN THE MICROWAVE ON WHILE YOUR DEVICE IS INSIDE_

Comment: YES - the oven MIGHT have damaged the router. If it has then you probably have more leakage than when the over was designed and built. If there is significantly more leakage than designed for it could be dangerous to people. If you find yourself hotheaded or going blind it may be an indication that the microwave is faulty :-) :-(. If the door is leaking (as happens but not commonly) - usually along a seam, then children standing close to the door may be at extra hazard. A portable telephone moved around the outside of a leaking over can act as an OK informal "sniffer".

Comment: When I was concerned that my workplace had old leaking ovens for the employees to use, I bought one of these:  https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0027AIL7A/  They were fine. And of course, right after that, they started testing and certifying them.

Answer (score 2):

> More to the point, is my microwave dangerous to people in the house?

It could be, although significant power needs to be leaking for it to be dangerous: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microwave_burn

> Assuming the (900 Watt Panasonic brand) microwave is to blame for the original WiFi performance issue, could it also be possible that the leaked RF energy has physically damaged the WiFi router's transceiver circuitry?

Absolutely, although this would take significant energy. If your router has a 'site survey' feature then use that to check if the local area has suddenly sprung a number of access points on the same channels, phone apps that show the local WiFi environment are available too.

Normally operating microwave ovens do not interfere to a noticeable extent with WiFi networks, so I would suspect that your oven is leaking to a greater-than-normal extent and that replacing it would be very wise.

Comment: Note that even small amounts of power leaking can cause cataracts over time.

Answer (score 1):

Before you assume your router is damaged, you should first shut it off and restart it.

It probably maintains a list of wifi channels where it has seen a lot of intereference, and avoids those channels.  Over time, it may have simply "black listed" all the available channels because of too much intereference.  A shutdown and restart should clear the list.

A microwave oven in good shape should not emit enough radiation to be dangerous.  It can, however, easily emit enough to interfere with wifi. Wifi uses comparatively weak signals, so it doesn't take a lot to cause interference.

If you have reason to suspect that your microwave oven is damaged, then replace it.

"Reason to suspect damage" includes:

- Oven was dropped
- Visible damage to the door or the door opening
- Visible damage to the grid in the glass window of the door
- Extreme age (bought it when your children were born, and you now have grandchildren.)

Comment: Rebooting the router is my standard go-to tactic when things go a bit flaky with either the WiFi or the broadband.  Good point about the channel blacklisting though.